# java add a root element to a xml document

Tags: java, json, xml

I have a JSON string **array** coming from a **simple JSON** library, and I want to create an XML for that string.

i did this using **json.org** library.

```
org.json.JSONArray jsonObject = new org.json.JSONArray(giveJson());
        return XML.toString(jsonObject);
```

where *giveJSON* is a function to give me the string of a JSON array. my problem is that the resulting xml is from this style:

```
<array>
</array>
<array>
</array>
```

it has no root element and as you know without a root element, the xml becomes invalid to most of the libraries specially iOS library. help me please to add a root to that xml string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your `JSONArray` to `JSONObject` by creating an instance of JSONObject as below:-

```
JSONObject rootObject= new JSONObject();
rootObject.put("root", <YOUR_JSONARRAY>);
```

Comment: what library are you talking about ? there are jsonobject in both libraries

Comment: You can use it from the one you are currently  getting `JSONArray`.

Comment: couldn't figure it out myself, i have two JSON libraries, please could you give me a working code to test your answer ?

Comment: `org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = new org.json.JSONArray(giveJson());
org.json.JSONObject rootObject = new org.json.JSONObject();
rootObject.put("root", jsonArray);
return XML.toString(jsonObject);`

Comment: your code throws this exception `This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 91: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.`

Comment: i checked the resulting xml, and it still has no one root, it has many roots

Comment: this worked for me `org.json.JSONArray jsonObject = new org.json.JSONArray(giveJson());
    String xml = XML.toString(jsonObject); xml =
    "<players>"+xml+"</players>"; return xml;`

Comment: You might have copied some special character during copying

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your xml format for the given json under specific xml root tag using the following method from **org.json** library.

```
JSONObject rootObject= new JSONObject();
rootObject.put("root", <YOUR_JSONARRAY>);
XML.toString(rootObject, "rootTag");
```

Comment: The overloaded XML.toString method does the job.